# I want to apply the parameters in the ui router dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I have some parameters for category's URL like /:rootcategory/:sub/:sub which is dynamic and for product I have to route like /product/:productname/:producturl..... It is working good using ui-sref but when I come on the URL and refresh it the config got confused and in both URL case it sends me on the category page.

```
.state('category3',{
        url: '/:name1/:name2/:name3',
        templateUrl: 'template/product/productsgridpage.html',
        controller: 'categoryCtrl',
        parent: 'productpagelayout'
    })
.state('product', {
            url: '/product/:name1/:name2',
            templateUrl: 'template/product/detailpage.html',
            controller: 'productCtrl',
            parent: 'productpagelayout',
        })
```

Comment: cant you just add /category/ to the beginning of the URL like how you have done for product. it may resolve your issue.

Comment: But I want to have a url for category like electronics/computer/tab and for products like products/hplaptop5050/hp-laptop

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer:**

The problem was category also validates product pages, url parameter of category state (`/:name1/:name2/:name3`) will accept (`/product/disc/test`) because name1 does not have any special checks to restrict the keyword `products` from not passing through. So what I suggest is have a regex check which will restrict the keyword product, so that this issue will not occour.

The regex for category will be like

`url: '/{name1:\b(?!\bproduct\b)\w+\b}/:name2/:name3',`

if name1 parameter starts with product the regex check will fail and category state will not be entered, so it will go to product state, this is what is needed by us.

```
.state('category3',{
    url: '/{name1:\b(?!\bproduct\b)\w+\b}/:name2/:name3',
    templateUrl: 'template/product/productsgridpage.html',
    controller: 'categoryCtrl',
    parent: 'productpagelayout'
})
.state('product', {
        url: '/product/:name1/:name2',
        templateUrl: 'template/product/detailpage.html',
        controller: 'productCtrl',
        parent: 'productpagelayout',
})
```

**Previous Answer:**

Since you pass **"products/hplaptop5050/hp-laptop"** it is taking products parameter as a category itself, thus goes to category instead, you need a static variable or even an unique input variable so that it does not get confused, might I suggest something like **"/{categoryid:int}/:name1/:name2/:name3"** or **"/0/:name1/:name2/:name3"**, so that we have a clear difference from the product and category page.

```
.state('category3',{
        url: '/{categoryid:int}/:name1/:name2/:name3',
        templateUrl: 'template/product/productsgridpage.html',
        controller: 'categoryCtrl',
        parent: 'productpagelayout'
    })
.state('product', {
            url: '/product/:name1/:name2',
            templateUrl: 'template/product/detailpage.html',
            controller: 'productCtrl',
            parent: 'productpagelayout',
        })
```

Please read the section state declaration page from UI router docs, you can come up with a different approch if needed.

Reference: [ui router state docs](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/state.statedeclaration.html#url)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to have is like flipcart apllication in which all the categories comes dynamically and even the product name with url not any static keyword.

Comment: @Amansharma if you want the routing as it is, ignore the product key alone, url has a custom regex parameter so `url: '/{name1:\b(?!\bproduct\b)\w+\b}/:name2/:name3'` it will exclude the product keyword alone. dont have the facility to test it, check it if possible. the URL parameter can also take a regex expression inside.

Comment: Thank you . But here,name1 is not productname it is category name.then what happens when I write /name1;categoryname/ or /{name1:\b(?!\categoryname\b)\w+\b}/ .both are same or not?